# Getting Unsupported image type. GD driver is only able to decode JPG, PNG, GIF or WebP files while uploading image

Tags: laravel, intervention

I have integrated [Intervention Image](https://github.com/Intervention/image) library (v-2.5) into my laravel application (v-5.1) to resize images. It is working fine in local server, but when i deploy it to live server i'm getting this error: `Unsupported image type. GD driver is only able to decode JPG, PNG, GIF or WebP files.`
. My image size is 18kb and its mime type is jpg. So there is nothing wrong with my image. Here is my code that i'm using for convertion and saving to server:

```
            foreach ($request->images as $file) {
                // getting file name with extension
                $imageName = getFileName($file);

                $homeworkImage = new HomeworkImage();
                $homeworkImage->tbl_homework_id = $homework->homework_id;
                $homeworkImage->image_name = $imageName;

                if ($homeworkImage->save()) {
                    // $file->move('uploads/homework', $imageName);

                    $image_resize = Image::make($file->getRealPath());
                    $image_resize->resize(300, 300);
                    $image_resize->save('uploads/homework/' . $imageName);
                }
            }
```

If i try to upload the image normally, that it is working fine. Can anyone point me out if i'm missing something!

Comment: I simply where able to debug after adding, `'throw' =>true,` to my driver within `config/filesystem.php` in my case the issue was a permission with AWS S3, and because of ACL please select "ACLs enabled" and then keep `Bucket owner preferred`.